# DataTable is not updating after editing html table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

MY datatable is not updating after editing the table row value using normal javascript. Table value is changing in view. But when i tried to take datatable data, it is taking older value..

Here is my table:

```
 <table id="Status" style="width:100%" class="table table-bordered">
                                    <thead style="background-color:#E0EEEE">
                                        <tr>
                                            <th style="width:10px" class=""></th>
                                            <th>Status</th>
                                            <th class="hidden">Seq No</th>
                                            <th class="hidden">Created by</th>
                                            <th class="hidden">Created date</th>
                                            <th class="hidden">Updated by</th>
                                            <th class="hidden">Updated date</th>
                                            <th class="hidden">RowVersion</th>
                                            <th style="width:40px">Edit</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>

                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
```

I am initialising datatable using this:

```
var StatusDataTable = $('#Status').DataTable({
            "fixedHeader": true,
            "lengthMenu": [[5, 10, 25, -1], [5, 10, 25, "All"]],
            "bSort": false,
            "scrollX": true,
            "oLanguage": {

                "sInfoEmpty": '',
                "sEmptyTable": "No Data Available",
            }

        });
```

am editing the table content using this code:

```
td[1].innerHTML = model.Name; td[2].innerHTML = model.SequenceNumber;
                            td[5].innerHTML = json.result.UpdatedBy; td[6].innerHTML = json.result.UpdatedDate; td[7].innerHTML = json.result.RowVersion;
                            tr.context.id = json.result.TaskStatusId;
```

but when am trying to take the datatable data, getting old values only.

```
var data1 = StatusDataTable.row(index).data();
var data2 = StatusDataTable.row(index + order).data();
```

I have already edited the correspondent column of data1. But still am getting the old value in data1.

Comment: try calling `draw()` after update..

Comment: F12, what errors are in the console?

Comment: I tried with draw also .. but still it is not working..

Comment: No error in console

Answer (score 0):

shouldn't you be updating the datatable using the datatable apis?  something like

```
table.rows().every(function(rowIdx, tableLoop, rowLoop) {
    var self = this;
    var d = this.data();
   d[2] = model.SequenceNumber
   d[5] = json.result.UpdatedBy
        self.data(d);
        self.invalidate();
    });
  table.draw();
```